# How do I make changes to spamassassin under zimbra?

Tags: spamassassin, zimbra, amavis

We are running a zimbra installation which uses spamassassin to filter mail. I have not installed this myself so I am not completely sure if this is a plain vanilla installation. The zimbra installation is located in /opt/zimbra/.

I am trying to disable the bayes and awl filters in spamassasin but nothing I do seems to have any effect.

I have tried setting "use_bayes 0" in both /opt/zimbra/conf/salocal.cf and /opt/zimbra/conf/spamassassin/local.cf without any effect. I have tried both restarting amavis using zmamavisdctl as well as restarting the full server after making my changes.

I have also tried removing 23_bayes.cf and 60_awl.cf from /opt/zimbra/conf/spamassassin/. Likewise, with no effect at all.

Any clues as to what I am doing wrong would be very helpful :-)

Update: Also tried salocal.cf.in without any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.. the problem turned out to be the server setup and me not changing the configuration on the right server ;-)

For any one else who might stumble upon this, the right approach was to change the configuration in /opt/zimbra/conf/spamassassin/local.cf and restart amavis using zmamavisdctl stop and start.

Answer (score 1):

Update for Zimbra 8.5+ 
According to the documentation (and to my tests) the file is now in : 
/opt/zimbra/data/spamassassin/localrules/

cf https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Anti-spam_Strategies